# How to port C library into into Android studio JNI folder

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, arm, cross-platform, embedded-linux

I have a program, which I have compiled using the arm toolchain in NDK. Now I want to use it as a library; put it in the JNI folder and call the functions from my main activity. I want to know how to go about this efficiently and intelligently. I copied all the files, and folders over to the JNI folder. What do I do about the make files in my native C code? Can I modify them to fit the JNI setup? Can anyone help with what items I need to address please? Note, my question is not about porting the native code, rather how to do it effectively. And I am trying to figure out if there are any automation tools in IDE that would help me do this please.

Right now, I get the following error, which I believe tells me that the old make file I copied over is not producing a file that is needed by the project? Am I right?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /home/sansari/ndk/android-ndk-r10d/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKSample/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKSample/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKSample/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/lib APP_ABI=all
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    make: *** No rule to make target `/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKSample/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/myLib//home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKSample/app/src/main/jni/tools/arm-eabi-4.7/lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.7/crtn.o', needed by `/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKSample/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libmyLib.so'.  Stop.
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sansari.ndksample"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    ndk {
        moduleName ="myLib"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

The story behind this project is that I created it using a tutorial. In it, the author used mylib. So the error I am getting says that the make file I just moved into the JNI folder does not have a line for building mylib.so. Is that right? I looked at the make file at the root of my C code, and that does not look anything like target/dependency structure that I read about in the first few chapters of GNU make. Can you help me find the make file I need to update in order to build mylib.so?

I found some information about my question. By default build.gradle ignores the existing make files in a native project. And you have to put in your own Android.mk and Application.mk files in the Android Studio.

Comment: What does your Android.mk look like (or build.gradle if you're using Android Studio)?

Answer (score 0):

I found out I have to add Android.mk and application.mk to a native project in Android Studio if I am looking to port a large project into Android Studio.